# How do I make a unit test out of my code in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

So I'm doing a simple poker test in which I have to display the players' names and their hands, and the player who has the higher hand wins. For this test, there are no card suits and ranks (e.g. ten of spades, jack of diamonds), just the type of hand the player is supposed to have (e.g. royal flush, straight, high card, etc). The output should be like this:

```
Player 1, Jane's hand is: Full House
Player 2, John's hand is: One Pair
Winner: Jane (Full House)
```

So now, I have all the logic working for this (which you'll see below). However, I'm now supposed to make a unit test for this. I've seen some tutorials but if you see my code below, I don't think it's suitable for a unit test. If anyone can help me fix my code for unit testing, then I highly appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
public class PokerGame
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Names of the players
        string player1Name, player2Name;

        // The array of the poker hands
        string[] pokerHands =
        {
            "High Card", "One Pair", "Two Pair", "Three of a Kind", "Straight", "Flush",
            "Full House", "Four of a Kind", "Straight Flush", "Royal Flush"
        };

        // This will prompt the players to type their name
        Console.Write("Enter Player 1: ");
        player1Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Player 2: ");
        player2Name = Console.ReadLine();

        // This Random object will deal random hands accordingly
        Random randomHand = new Random();

        // The random hand index assigned to Player 1
        int hand1 = randomHand.Next(pokerHands.Length);

        // The random hand index assigned to Player 2
        int hand2 = randomHand.Next(pokerHands.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Player 1, " + player1Name + "'s, hand is: " + pokerHands[hand1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Player 2, " + player2Name + "'s, hand is: " + pokerHands[hand2]);

        // If the random hand index for Player 1 is greater than that for Player 2
        if (hand1 > hand2)
        {
            // Then Player 1 wins
            Console.WriteLine("Winner: " + player1Name + " (" + pokerHands[hand1] + ").");
        }
        // But if it's the opposite
        else if (hand1 < hand2)
        {
            // Player 2 wins
            Console.WriteLine("Winner: " + player2Name + " (" + pokerHands[hand2] + ").");
        }
        // And if they have the same hands
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's a tie!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

EDIT: After getting help from some friends and from people on Facebook (LOL), I managed to refactor some of my code into this:

```
public class PokerDealer
    {
        string[] hands =
            {
                "High Card", "One Pair", "Two Pair", "Three of a Kind", "Straight", "Flush",
                "Full House", "Four of a Kind", "Straight Flush", "Royal Flush"
            };

        public void DealCards(int hand1, int hand2, string name1, string name2)
        {
            Random randomHand = new Random();

            hand1 = randomHand.Next(hands.Length);
            hand2 = randomHand.Next(hands.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Player 1, " + name1 + "'s hand: " + hands[hand1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2, " + name2 + "'s hand: " + hands[hand2]);

            CheckWinner(hand1, hand2, name1, name2);
        }

        public int CheckWinner(int win1, int win2, string name1, string name2)
        {
            int winner;

            if (win1 > win2)
            {
                winner = win1;
                Console.WriteLine("Winner: " + name1 + " (" + hands[winner] + ")");
            }
            else if (win1 < win2)
            {
                winner = win2;
                Console.WriteLine("Winner: " + name2 + " (" + hands[winner] + ")");
            }
            else
            {
                winner = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("It's a tie!");
            }

            return winner;
        }
    }
```

DealCards() is basically my randomizer (gives out random cards) and CheckWinner(), well, checks who has the winning card. Also, I've already run unit tests for the winning conditions of both players, and they work! Now here are some problems:

1. How will I now test if they have the same card? (The last condition)
2. I'm trying to run a test for DealCards() to see if the players indeed get random cards and to see if it doesn't go out of the range (0 to 9; probably more important). For this one, I don't know how I will assert the latter condition. Here's the testing method:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void RandomHand()
        {
            // Tests if players are given a random hand within the range
            PokerDealer pd = new PokerDealer();
            Random randomHand = new Random();

            int randomHandIndex = randomHand.Next(10);
            pd.DealCards(randomHandIndex, randomHandIndex, "Player 1", "Player 2");
        }
```

Comment: Indeed it is not, you need some units. Basically move your code from Main into some classes and then test each of them. Classes for Hand, Player, Winner and perhaps Game, for instance

Comment: @TonyHopkinson so just make individual classes? Because from my understanding, I'm supposed to tests methods in unit testing, right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Writing unit tests is easier if you practice TDD, rather than writing a bunch of code  first and then thinking about testing

Comment: @auburg Yeah unfortunately, I haven't practiced TDD. I wish I came across this earlier when I was studying programming. :/

Comment: @MiguelLorenzoPagkatipunan, "it's not suitable for unit tests". You got the point. Try to convert them into small and pure pieces as much as possible. And by practising  TDD, auburg trying to say like, practice TDD while developing this piece of code

Comment: @ilkerkaran Yeah, I'm doing that right now. And like I said, I wish I knew TDD earlier but then again, it's better to still learn it right now than learn it not at all. Lol.

Comment: Even if you don't use TDD, should write code that can be unit tested. Using SOLID will do that.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm sorry but what's SOLID?

Comment: @MiguelLorenzoPagkatipunan - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID. Bear in mind that the linked wiki is literally the tip of a very, very large - albeit useful - iceberg :)

Comment: @MiguelLorenzoPagkatipunan - also, just wanted to say, do not be worried that you cannot unit test this code right now. You have an excellent opportunity to learn how to refactor this code into good object-oriented C#, by using tests to drive your design. Learning that is worth an awful lot of experience!

Comment: SOLID is a lot of things, but the key take for your next bit of learning is each bit of code does a single thing. E.g you have a method/class that works out the winning hand, then you can do Win, Lose and Draw tests. Will seem a bit overboard here, but it's good practice and good practice.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code better suited for unit testing, my advice would be: Only the **Main()** method should print text via **Console.Write()**. All the other methods should only return values. This way your tests can call the methods and check your assumptions about the return values. For example, **CheckWinner()** should return the text it currently writes to the console so you can verify in a test that the string returned by **CheckWinner()** (maybe rename to **GetResultText()** or something) matches the input parameters.

As for testing certain scenarios like both players having the same hand there are two options:

- Create a mockup for Random. This way you can control which values it returns when used within a unittest. This is an advanced topic but it is a very useful technique for unit testing. Google C# mocking.
- Use the same seed for the Random-instance every time (of course only when testing!); this way the values returned by the Next() calls will be always the same and you can use them for testing. For example

  ```
  Random r = new Random(9);
  Console.WriteLine(r.Next(10));
  Console.WriteLine(r.Next(10));
  ```

will give you two fours in a row - every time.

As for your last point, how to test if ranodm returns random numbers within the given range. Why would you do that? Random it is not part of your code, so it does not make sense for you to test it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, although I'm not sure how I'm gonna go along with removing **Console.Write()** parts in the **CheckWinner()** and **DealCards()**. I did that because I implemented typing the player names in the **Main()** method but then the names vanish when I run **DealCards()**. I hope I'm making sense lol.